# Proof that a relation is in FP

Tags: complexity-theory

How we can prove that the relation: $R= \left\{0,1\right\}^*\times \left\{0,1\right\}^* \in FP$
I understand that we need to find a polytime algorithm to decide whether $(x,y) \in R$ since $(x,y)\in R= \left\{0,1\right\}^*\times \left\{0,1\right\}^*$
How can we find this? And this is enough to prove that $R \in FP$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $R \in \mathsf{FP}$ you need to show that there is a deterministic poly-time algorithm $A$ that takes $x$ as input and outputs a $y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$.

A possible choice of $A$ is the algorithm that outputs $\varepsilon$ (the empty word) regardless of $x$. Indeed, $(x, \varepsilon) \in R$.